# html table using for loop with first column static?

Tags: php, html

**i want to populate table that has first field static and other fields are coming from database using for loop**

blank column are coming from database using for loop and i have to insert first column statically how do i do that?

```
  for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
   }
```

i want these kind of result

```
  story  blank blank blank
  games  blank blank blank
  number blank blank blank
```

Comment: i have to create a table that has first column inserted by manually and other columns are coming from databse

Comment: Please provide sample data from your query result

Comment: needs to provide more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to read more about how to create a table and its rows (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++):?>
    <tr>
        <td>my static value</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php endfor;?>
```

Also, please keep those static values to an array and add them using the same `for`.

```
<?php 
$myArrayWithMyStaticValues = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$myArrayWithMyStaticValues[$i];?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php endfor;?>
```

But be careful because you need to have the same number of items in your array as the `for` condition.